# What is better for a host server for web servers - more threads/cores or bigger CPU?

Tags: cpu, virtualization

Let's say I have 5 VMs (4 tomcat servers and one db). Not very crowdy (100 distinct users at peak hours). I'm wondering is it better to have e.g. 3GHz CPU with 4 cores or 2GHz with 8 cores?

Also would you say that the problem is not enough cores if 1 minute CPU load peak over 3 and average around 0.9, but overall CPU utilization stays well below 20%? My intuition says more cores (even with much lower GHz) would lower CPU load and make the server respond more snappy... But not sure.

Oh, one thing might be important - the virtualization is based on Proxmox 4 with LXC in my case. But I'm guessing other virtualizations wouldn't be that much different.

Comment: It is impossible for us to compare two CPUs without knowing which two CPUs we're comparing. Knowing how many cores they have and their clock speed is useful, but not sufficient to compare them.

Comment: My question is not about specific processors. It's about a more general concept about cores vs frequency. You can assume all other parameters of the processor are the same or close (as is the case with some Intel processor which tend to have more cores or higher frequency).

Comment: There is no real useful answer in general. For example, all other things being equal, more cores don't help once you max out the memory bandwidth. Same is true for a higher clock speed. At a minimum, you'd need to know the actual CPUs to give a useful answer. Otherwise, this is an "is a truck better than a car" question. It depends on what truck, what car, and exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well I did say what I'm delivering ;-). I also did say what are the challenges (high CPU load with low utilization). I didn't mention memory (I assume you mean RAM), because it is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, go with the 8 cores x 2 GHz = 16 "GHz" worth of cores, compared wirh 3 x 4 = 12 "GHz" worth of cores.    It would seem that your load is amenable to multiple cores (lots of users, multiple VMs let alone threads), so your system will take advantage of the additional cores.

Of-course, this assumes that the frequency is the only important thing about cores.  Its not.  I'd have a look at www.cpubenchmark.net for each of the CPUs and go with the one with a faster "pass mark".

You can't tell too much about performance from just CPU load - particularly on multi-core CPU's.  "Naively" you can take the load and divide by the number of cores, and if thats < 1 you are OK.  Of-course, that doesn't paint anything like a meaningful picture - I'd run "vmstat" and see what is taking up the resources - unless SYS + User is high, I'd look elsewhere at the bottleneck.  (Disk IO, database locks).   that said, a peak load < 4 on a 4 core CPU typically means the server is coping - but not optimum.   More cores are can make the system snappier without necessarily affecting the "load" numbers.

You will probably find your system is IO/Disk bound - but thats a guess.

Comment: I think multiplying the clock speed by the number of cores makes no sense at all and provides a completely useless number. As just one reason, if the memory is the limiting factor, more cores does nothing. Another is that two CPUs can have cores that run at the same clock speed but produce wildly different instruction per second rates. You point out these kinds of things in the second and third paragraphs, so why spout borderline nonsense in the first?

Comment: "All else being equal, go with the 8 cores x 2 GHz = 16 "GHz" worth of cores, compared with 3 x 4 = 12 "GHz" worth of cores." - This concept makes no sense at all.  If you had just pointed out that having 8 cores compared to 4 cores, for 5 VMs to split was a better choice, then I might have found this answer helpful.  Of course it isn't just 5 VMs it's a host operating system and 5 VMs that must share the resources of a CPU which means, honestly, even 8 cores likely isn't enough.